# Firebase Cloud Functions cannot read nitro generated index.mjs file

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, nuxtjs3

EDIT:

I want to deploy a Nuxt3 app to Firebase Hosting. I've set the deployment preset for Nitro to "firebase" `NITRO_PRESET=firebase`, and the build step works fine. However, when I run `firebase deploy`, I get an error saying:

```
There was an error reading .output/server/package.json: 
.output/server/index.js does not exist, can't deploy Cloud Functions
```

I checked the `.output/server` directory, and saw that Nitro generated a file called `index.mjs`. I checked to see if Cloud Functions also works with `.mjs` files, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I looked for possible solutions but couldn't find anything; I tried reinstalling my modules, but no luck. Do I have something misconfigured or broken?

I'm following this tutorial:
https://nitro.unjs.io/deploy/providers/firebase

I'm using WSL2 Ubuntu on Windows 11, and the project folder is inside the linux filesystem.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview"

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/google-fonts": "^3.0.0-0",
    "@types/three": "^0.143.1",
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.9.3",
    "sass": "^1.54.5",
    "three": "^0.143.0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2"
  }
}
```

My firebase.json:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "./.output/server",
    "runtime": "nodejs16",
    "ignore": [
      "node_modules",
      ".git",
      "firebase-debug.log",
      "firebase-debug.*.log"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "site": "my-site",
    "public": ".output/public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "server"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After the build step:

```
Σ Total size: 19.6 MB (3.21 MB gzip)
✔ You can deploy this build using npx firebase deploy
```

After the deployment step:

```
i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment

Error: There was an error reading .output/server/package.json:

.output/server/index.js does not exist, can't deploy Cloud Functions
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is that you're having.  What are you trylng to accomplish?  What do you mean by "can't be read"?  Is there an error message?  What steps do we take to reproduce the issue?  Please edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using the default `node-server` preset. To deploy the Nuxt 3 app to Firebase, you must set the `NITRO_PRESET` to `firebase` in your environment.

```
NITRO_PRESET=firebase

npm run build
```

The CLI should prompt you to run `npx firebase deploy` once the build is completed.

[image]

Then run the command and it will deploy the application to Firebase hosting and functions.

You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://nitro.unjs.io/deploy/providers/firebase#deploy-to-firebase-hosting-via-cli).

Comment: I've made sure to set the env variable to `firebase` before every build. Unfortunately, I'm still getting errors. Could anything else be the cause?

Comment: @Apricitine how did you set the env var and what is your OS? If it just says "You can preview this build using `node .output/server/index.mjs`" and doesn't prompt to use `npx firebase deploy` then I doubt if the env was working.

Comment: I ran `NITRO_PRESET=firebase` to set the env variable and then `npm run build` to run the build step. It actually did say `✔ You can deploy this build using npx firebase deploy`.

Comment: @Apricitine and you still get the same error? Can you remove the trailing slash `/` in `firebase.json`, that seems to be the issue. Just `"source": "./.output/server",` you seem to have a slash after server in your question

Comment: Oops, I forgot to remove that after some previous tests. I'm still getting the error... :(
could it just be a bug?

Comment: @Apricitine did you forget to run `npm install -D firebase-admin firebase-functions firebase-functions-test`? I can't see these devDependencies in your package.json. Also do run `npm run build` again (ensure the preset is firebase) and then try deploying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247735/discussion-between-apricitine-and-dharmaraj).

Comment: Wow, it worked, sort of. The old error is gone, but after running `firebase deploy` I'm getting this: ```Error: An unexpected error has occurred.```

Comment: @Apricitine  It'll be best to post another question for the new error with output of `firebase deploy --debug` logs. If the _original_ issue has been resolved then you can accept/upvote the answer so others will know this particular issue has been resolved.